# Error "There was no channel actively listening" on HTTPS

Tags: wcf, azure, wcf-binding

So, I'm supporting in a WCF that is having some interesting problems. In the application log file, it has appeared the following error:

```
There was no channel actively listening at 'http://hostanme.domain/Integration/IntegrationService.svc'. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening.
```

The case is that the application is configured to receive only requests in HTTPS, and if some external requests come with HTTP, it responds with a "404 Not Found". The point is that the error request up always comes HTTP and the hostname of the machine in the URL domain. We contemplated a lot here in the office whether it would be if the application calls this URL after the IIS recylce, but we are still on this question, and we can not repeat this error.

Has anyone had a similar situation , or know how to solve this case?

Answer (score 0):

try to run this command :

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Comment: Sometimes this may be related to domaged aspnet installation, this command Installs ASP.NET 4 and updates existing applications to use the ASP.NET 4 version of the application pool. It updates both the IIS Classic mode and the IIS Integrated mode handler and script mappings in the IIS metabase.